# How to install InteliJ on Mac? (MacOS Sierra)

Tags: java, macos, ide

Trying to see should I download and install dmg for *InteliJ* or use `brew cask install`?

***What is recommendation and how to do with brew?***

(looking for newest community version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple version for intelij community and paid, for paid you need a license.Here are some links how to install inteliJ

https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/intellij-idea-mac.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installing-and-launching.html

With brew:-

http://macappstore.org/intellij-idea/

Install the App

Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
Run in Terminal app:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask 2> /dev/null
and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
Run:
brew cask install intellij-idea
Done! You can now use IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks...  `brew cask install intellij-idea
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2017.2.5.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask intellij-idea
==> Installing Cask intellij-idea
==> Moving App 'IntelliJ IDEA.app' to '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app'.
  intellij-idea was successfully installed!`

Comment: Is `brew cask install intellij-idea` for free or paid version? (it is asking me for account/evaluation email and free evaluation show as 30 days only)

Comment: Yeah that was paid version. Found out from that link above about CE: `brew cask uninstall intellij-idea

brew cask install intellij-idea-ce
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-2017.2.5.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask intellij-idea-ce
==> Installing Cask intellij-idea-ce
==> Moving App 'IntelliJ IDEA CE.app' to '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app'.
  intellij-idea-ce was successfully installed!`